# Ruby on Rails Full Text Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, full-text-search, words

How can i search full text with sentence and search any word matched or different configuration

example:

"professor john smith" is searching in model title

it have to display result which matched the "proffessor john smith", "professor john" ", "proffesson smith"

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of fulltext search technologies supports rails. elasticsearch and solar search ar eone of them

Rails cast about integrating solar search is [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot)

Answer (score 1):

There are some technologies compatible with rails. For example sunspot, as @scottxu wrote, or elasticsearch, as @knotito said. Good solution also - [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) (fast and lite) and [thinking_sphinx](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx) gem. If you use postgresql as database, and you do not want use external solutions - you can choose [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem, that emplements fulltext search with pg technologies only. I prefer elasticsearch, but it requires JVM, and some people don't like this.

updated:

how to use pg_search:
First, you should add pg_search to gemfile, make `bundle install`, and add to your model something like:

```
include PgSearch
pg_search_scope :search_by_title, :against => :title
```

if you didn't do it before.

After, you can try to test it in rails console:
Professor.search_by_title('professor smith')

Comment: hej avy. I just install pg_search but dont know how to configure it  do find "proffesson smith". maybe you know corrent congiguration for this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For fulltext searches you can use [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

To implement that you can follow [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)

description:
Sunspot is a Ruby library for expressive, powerful interaction with the Solr search engine. Sunspot is built on top of the RSolr library, which provides a low-level interface for Solr interaction; Sunspot provides a simple, intuitive, expressive DSL backed by powerful features for indexing objects and searching for them.